# animate svg with css without using inline svg

Tags: html, css, object, svg, svg-animate

i'm quite a newbie (started one week ago) to html, css and so on and i wanna create an animated svg graphic in my website.
so far i managed to create a good result with an inline svg:
http://codepen.io/einserpasch/pen/xbWwOR

```
<body bgcolor="#999">

 <div id="menue"></div>
 <div id="titel">
<svg id="einserpasch" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 285.2 134.2">
<style type="text/css">       
</style>
<path 
/* here comes the crazy long code of the svg - see codepen */
/>
</svg>     </div>
</body>
```

and the accompanied css:

```
#einserpasch {
height:133px;
fill:#000;
animation-name: glow-grey;
animation-duration: 10s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes glow-grey {
0% { fill: black; }
100% { fill:#999; }
}

#einserpasch:hover {
fill:#009;
/* another idea i've had, but not so important */ 
}

#titel {
background:#999;
height:133px;
width:555px;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
#menue {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background:#000;
padding:0px;
width:150px  ;
height:100%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 75px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 75px;
}
```

but i dont like this solution. 
the code in the html file is way to long if i wanna proceed with the website. so i tried <image>, <object> or <?php include ?> to link to an external svg or php(containing the svg) file. these solutions were showing the graphic but no animation.
**so how can place the information of the vector graphic in an external file, link it to the html (or css) and animate it using css?**
i suppose it can work with one of these approaches but - as i am a newbie - it didn't to me.
i hope someone can help me out with that and the solution is not too complex...

thanks in advance!
ps.: yes, i like the complexity of the graphic. making it more simple (thus shortening the code) is not an option ;)

Comment: Would it be possible to load the SVG asychronously with Javascript?

Comment: @Jaxo: maybe. i have no clue about javascript...

Comment: i **tried** linking the svg to the html like this: `<div id="titel"><img src="bilder/einser_simpel.svg" id="einserpasch"/></div>`
or: `<div id="titel"><object src="bilder/einser_simpel.svg" id="einserpasch"/></div>`
or: `<div id="titel"><?php include("bilder/einser_simpel.svg"); ?></div>`
like this they didn't even take the `fill` as defined in the css.

Comment: PHP includes are for including PHP code, not arbitrary files, which would be why it isn't working.  Try using `<?php echo file_get_contents("bilder/einser_simpel.svg"); ?>` :) .

Comment: @Jaxo so do i just paste something like `<div class="topic"><?php echo file_get_contents("pictures/hourglass.svg"); ?></div>` in my `<body>` of the html file (when i have a menue bar for example), or do i have to define something else at another place. e.g. in the `<head>` or in an external file?

Comment: PHP doesn't read HTML, nor does it care what's already in there.  That code you posted should be fine!